# Generate files at different location using openapi-generator

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using the OpenAPI generator to generate my APIs. My requirement is that I want to generate at different locations. For example I wish to generate and save models in some other directory than the service class, but there seems to be just one option `outputDir`. Can someone suggest a way to generate files at different locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outputDir` is the only option to customize the output location for *all* files at the moment.

If you want to put some auto-generated files in a particular location, I would recommend a script to post-process the output (e.g. move files around).

Comment: I solved the problem by making different tasks of the type `org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask` and then setting different `outputDir` for them